# str_replace in Twig

Tags: php, filter, str-replace, twig

I want to do  a simple str_replace in my twig template. I'm new to twig and probably I need to add new filter or sth like that or to use existing. How can I do this? Where can I find list of filters available?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  There are a number of filters and some HTML escaping built in to twig already: http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use this to replace `|` with `-` and replace `,` width `.`:

```
{{age|replace({'|': "-", "," : "."})}}
```

Example input `31|60,` comes out as `31-60.`

Answer (score 66):

To replace a string which is stored in twig variables:

```
{% set twig_content_variable= 'Testing to replace content'%}
{% set replace_value_var= 'Testing' %}
{% set replace_with_value_var = 'Testing complete' %} 

{{ twig_content_variable|replace({ (replace_value_var): replace_with_value_var }) }}
```

Comment: How to remove empty space?

Comment: @Guru like this {{ "apples and carrots"|replace(' ', '') }}

Comment: The documentation simply doesn't mention the parentheses because you don't need them.

Comment: @Capsule you'd think so, but for some strange reason, it doesn't replace without them, they don't have to be for explicit string key like `'some'`, but has to be around variable (probably some internal string=>key resolution)

Answer (score 10):

When we add a single quote inside a single quote then we face the error.

solution for that:-

```
{{description|replace({"\'": "&#039"})|raw }}
```

Answer (score 9):

Also, this could be useful for getting rid of (utf-8) language chars...

```
{{some_string|replace({'ć':'c','č':'c','š':'s','ž':'z','đ':'d','Ć':'C','Č':'C','Š':'S','Ž':'Z','Đ':'D'})}}
```

Comment: How about: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)`?

Comment: @umpirsky Hmmm, i think the code for twig goes something like this 
{{ data|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'iso that you want') }}, but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: Yes, mine was PHP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to replace . with "" , replace - width "" and : replace _ width "" :

- "" = nothing or NULL

  ```
  {{signature3.user.username|replace({'.': "", "-" : "","_":""})}}
  ```

input najim_el-guennouni, out as najimelguennouni.