# How to replace content's of custom tag, class or id?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-theming

I'm trying to use [str-replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) PHP String Functions for content of custom tag, class or id, in addition i want to understand Is it possible to use that or similar Functions in twig template?

To resolve this issue I wrote something like below code to my **ThemeName.theme:**

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
$variables['<div class="info">']= str_replace(
array('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
array('1','2','3','4','5','6'),
$variables['<div class="info">']
);
}
```

I Try out Many different ways but I can't get any result.I would be happy to hear what the problem is and guide me to To resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is discussion on this subject here:

[str_replace in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943880/str-replace-in-twig)

Accepted answer is pointing to replace filter:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

So something like:

```
{{some_string|replace({'A':'1','B':'2','C':'3','D':'4','E':'5','F':'6'})}}
```

should work.